# We have a kops based k8s cluster running on AWS with deployments using EFS as Persistent Volume; Now we would to migrate to EKS with PVC Deployments

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, persistent-volumes, kops

We have a kops based k8s cluster running on AWS with deployments using EFS as Persistent Volume; Now we would to migrate to EKS with PVC Deployments

could some one help me in migrating deployments using Persistent Volume claims to EKS cluster in AWS.

Answer (score 1):

You can not *move* `PersistentVolumeClaims` to another cluster, you need to re-create them in the new cluster. You need to backup the data and restore from backup in the new cluster.